# Setting maxlength of textbox with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textbox

I want to change the maxlength of a textbox with JavaScript or jQuery:  I tried the following but it didn't seem to help:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if((a[i].type!= 'radio')||(a[i].type!= 'checkbox'))
        a[i].maxlength = 5;
}
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].maxlength="3";

$().ready(function()
{
    $("#inputID").maxlength(6);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish on your first few lines but you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#ms_num").attr('maxlength','6');
});
```

Comment: this is not standard and doesn't work in IE7, 8 and 9 so avoid it.

Comment: @Dynamic Do you have any links/documentation to back this up? According to [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) and [Mozilla.Org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) These are still valid. Note in the Mozilla documentation it will only work for the following '<input>' tag types: text, email, search, password, tel, url

Comment: This is the correct way, Dynamic was incorrect. Its a standard attribute

Comment: @Kamlesh Numbers do not use lengths in the same respect as text. Use the `min` and `max` attributes instead.

Answer (score 31):

The max length property is camel-cased: <kbd>maxLength</kbd>

jQuery doesn't come with a maxlength method by default. Also, your document ready function isn't technically correct:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ms_num")[0].maxLength = 6;
    // OR:
    $("#ms_num").attr('maxlength', 6);
    // OR you can use prop if you are using jQuery 1.6+:
    $("#ms_num").prop('maxLength', 6);
});
```

Also, since you are using jQuery, you can rewrite your code like this (taking advantage of jQuery 1.6+):

```
$('input').each(function (index) {
    var element = $(this);
    if (index === 1) {
        element.prop('maxLength', 3);
    } else if (element.is(':radio') || element.is(':checkbox')) {
        element.prop('maxLength', 5);
    }
});

$(function() {
    $("#ms_num").prop('maxLength', 6);
});
```

Comment: looks like you answered at the exact same time!!

Comment: Actually when I wrote my answer there were no other posts, but directly after I posted my answer hunter's appeared below. Its a delicate balance between giving a quick answer and giving a full answer.

Answer (score 11):

without jQuery you can use

```
document.getElementById('text_input').setAttribute('maxlength',200);
```

Answer (score 5):

set the attribute, not a property

```
$("#ms_num").attr("maxlength", 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#yourTextBoxId').live('change keyup paste', function(){
    if ($('#yourTextBoxId').val().length > 11) {
        $('#yourTextBoxId').val($('#yourTextBoxId').val().substr(0,10));
    }
});
```

I Used this along with vars and selectors caching for performance and that did the trick ..

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing problem like me with **accepted answer**:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#ms_num").attr('maxlength','6');
});
```

You may use `on focus` instead of ready function:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#ms_num', function() {
{
    $(this).attr('maxlength','6');
});
```

This will make sure to set the maxlength attribute when the input field is focused or selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```
$('#inputID').keypress(function () {
    var maxLength = $(this).val().length;
    if (maxLength >= 5) {
        alert('You cannot enter more than ' + maxLength + ' chars');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetMaxLength () {
            var input = document.getElementById ("myInput");
            input.maxLength = 10;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" size="20" />
</body>
```

Comment: Because the question is about how to do that with JS or JQ.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetMaxLength () {
            var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            input.maxLength = 10;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" size="20" />
</body>
```