# Setting max length in bootstrap x-editable form

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to set max length for the text box in the bootstrap xeditable form.The thing is that the textbox  which appears is an in build feature of the form so i could not set maxlength as an html attribute.I tried it using jquery but its not working out.( I am not able to attach the screenshot)
Please help me to solve this,

Comment: if you cant attach the screenshot, you could at least attach the code.

Comment: also, consider adding a jsfiddle - you can start by forking [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/serra/7bw5t/)

Answer (score 16):

You can set HTML attributes by overwriting the template:

Such as:

```
$('#your_id').editable({
  tpl: '<textarea maxlength="250"></textarea>'
});
```

Comment: Be careful, because the maxlength attribute for a textarea is not supported by all browsers .. it is an HTML 5 attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp )

Comment: Solved my problem. Maybe you should also mention that it can be set via `data-tpl` attribute on the html element directly.

Comment: as per @G-Man suggestions this can be improved by using <input maxlength=12/> which is supported by every browser pretty much from ver1 and as per julealgon's suggestion we can add this attribute (data-tpl="<input maxlength=12/>") to <a> html rather than writing separately in Js file. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to set the `maxLength` attribute using jQuery, for instance like this:

```
$('#myBox').attr('maxlength', 6);
```

There is some more information [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6141680/322283).

But it is hard to tell from your question what you have tried. Please add the jQuery code you tried to your question, so we can better help you.

Comment: @Marijin: I tried exactly as you mentioned here. The problem is, consider a text box with id mybox1 which is inside mybox which is not a user defined (created) but is a integral part of mybox.I need to set max length for that mybox1.I tried using that id name mybox1 to setup the max length but its not working out.

Comment: Please add the html to your question, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a "inputclass" attribute you can pass so you can style it how you want to. Overriding tpl option might  be hairy because there are custom library classes applied to it.

Comment: I've set data-tpl without any problems.