# How to set the max value and min value of <input> in html5 by javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find out how to set the max value and min value of html5 type input by javascript or jquery.

```
<input type="number" max="???" min="???" step="0.5"/>
```

Would someone please guide

Comment: Did you try something ? Like `yourInput.max=33` ?

Comment: Firstly check if it is supported by your browser: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/04-minmaxstep.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting maxlength of textbox with javascript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141680/setting-maxlength-of-textbox-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @Vladimir It is a bit different thing...

Comment: @Vladimir I don't think he refers to that kind of min/max.

Comment: If you use jQuery, use $(".your_class_name_here").on("input", function () {})

Answer (score 75):

jQuery makes it easy to set any attributes for an element - just use the [`.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").attr({
       "max" : 10,        // substitute your own
       "min" : 2          // values (or variables) here
    });
});
```

The document ready handler is not required if your script block appears after the element(s) you want to manipulate.

Using a selector of `"input"` will set the attributes for *all* inputs though, so really you should have some way to identify the input in question. If you gave it an id you could say:

```
$("#idHere").attr(...
```

...or with a class:

```
$(".classHere").attr(...
```

Comment: @Bmd - Did *you* test it before commenting? It *does* work: https://jsfiddle.net/nbd0q2me/ - I only tested this in Chrome, but both the up/down buttons on the number input and the form submit button use the values set by the JS code shown. (And regardless of whether it works in *current* browsers - which it seems to - I tested it at the time I posted the answer and it worked back then.)

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
<input type="number" max="???" min="???" step="0.5" id="myInput"/>

$("#myInput").attr({
   "max" : 10,
   "min" : 2
});
```

Note:This will set max and min value only to single input

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
   $("input[type='number']").prop('min',1);
   $("input[type='number']").prop('max',10);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rbW/)

Comment: does not work for me in chrome browser.

Comment: @nilakanthasinghdeo: Please check the demo

Comment: Everything is wrong with @nilakanthasinghdeo 's fiddle. The input isn't `type="number"`, and you haven't actually set a `max` or `min` value....

Comment: Extending this answer, you may want to include a function to reset the input to the max/min value if the user types in a value that exceeds the limits. I wrote this jQuery for my own app: ```$('input[type="number"]').on('keyup', function(){
    if ($(this).val() > $(this).attr('max')*1) {
      $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
    }
  });```

Comment: yah ,it was not serving the purpose. Thanks for pointing out. Removing it