# attribute a max value to a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get something like this in jquery but I can't figure out how to set a "limit" to a desired value.

I've got an article with a basic price, at this price the user can sum some Addon that will increase the price.

ONLY if the user will select those addons they will receive a discount.

When a user selects these addons, the price will increase.

Now they can receive a discount that dynamically increases when a user clicks on an addon, but this discount limits to a preset value (in the example is 3000)

```
Example:

basicPrice = 10000;
addon_1 = 500
addon_2 = 700
addon_3 = 900
....


totalPrice =  basicPrice + addon_1 + addon_2 +addon_3

MaxDiscount = 3000;
actualDiscount= addon_1 + addon_2 + addon_2 ---> limit to MaxDiscount

finalPrice = totalPrice - actualDiscount
```

Comment: Totally unclear what you are asking. On your paragraphs. May be because of your English skill.

Comment: Sorry @Towkir I tried to made the question more clear

Comment: If I understand well what you're saying, all you need to do is compare actualDiscount to the MaxDiscount and if (actualDiscount > MaxDiscount) then actualDiscount = MaxDiscount.
It is up to you how you calculate the actualDiscount.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316709/how-to-set-the-max-value-and-min-value-of-input-in-html5-by-javascript-or-jque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this you are trying to accomplish,

Example:

```
basicPrice = 10000;
addon_1 = 500
addon_2 = 700
addon_3 = 900
....


totalPrice =  basicPrice + addon_1 + addon_2 +addon_3

if(totalPrice>basicPrice){

    MaxDiscount = 3000;
    actualDiscount= addon_1 + addon_2 + addon_2

    if(actualDiscount>MaxDiscount){
       actualDiscount = maxDiscount;
    }

    finalPrice = totalPrice - actualDiscount

}else{
    finalPrice = totalPrice;
}
```