# Restrict number of input in a form when selected in a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am wondering how to restrict number of input using maybe javascript/html (form validation) when selected a select input. SCENARIO: I have first a dropdown box where you can choose your country code for mobile number; once selected, ofcourse one must input their mobile number (length of the mobile number depending on what country code you have chosen, e.g. +63[philippines] and the users mobile number must only be 11 characters long). The following is my line of codes:

```
 <div class="input-append">
    <select name="mobile" tabindex="15" style="height: 30px; width: 80px;" required>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="Philippines") ?>>+63 (Philippines)</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="America") ?>>+1 (America)</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="UK") ?>>+44 (United Kingdom)</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="Japan") ?>>+81 (Japan)</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="Korea") ?>>+82 (Korea)</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($source) && $source=="China") ?>>+86 (China)</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="mobile_phone" tabindex="16" style="height: 30px; width: 127px;" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Phone Number" maxlength="11"required>
 </div>
```

thankyou for your kind responses!

Comment: Use min and max attributes check this http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/04-minmaxstep.html

Comment: Use onchange event of javascript.

Comment: I dont think so this facility works with Javascript. So user Jquery instead of Javascript other wise write you custom code as per option value.  See this link for jquery example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141680/setting-maxlength-of-textbox-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Is that so? i dont know what to with this because of the numerous choices in the dropdown box, making validation more difficult to do . Thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-list and some regular expressions:

```
 ^\+63\d{11}$ - must start with +63 followed by 11 digits
```

Good luck!